# Angular 2 create new project, and SQL

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, express

First, I am trying to setup Angular 2 with SQL Server but I don't know where to start to create new project. I have just finished using their quick start, and wanted to create my own. I searched their tutorial site, and no mention about creating new application at all. The only thing mentioned to start an app is by downloading or cloning from their git, which would give their quickstart. But there is no mention on how to create new app.

Second, I want to use angular as web front, and I've already deployed a node js apps using ExpressJS 4. So naturally I want to integrate angular with my existing backend but I am not sure on how to put angular there, especially Angular is using typescript.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

See https://cli.angular.io/ for how to create a new project.

Angular just makes http requests to the server. When you build your Angular client, just copy the created output to a directory the server serves.

You can't use SQL from Angular. Your server has to access the SQL database and provide a REST (or some other kind of remote API) for your Angular2 client that your server translates to SQL queries for your database and the result as response for the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can follow https://cli.angular.io/ for creating new project in angular.

Your project development will be very easy and simple. We can create compoments, modules, pipes, services etc from your command line interface.

Follow the below git link for commands to be followed , while developing Angular2 application.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Use http service to get data from your server in our appilcation.